# Retrieve all points within a given radius using quadkeys

Tags: bing-maps, quadtree

I'm new to GIS concepts and I'm learning about quadkeys and usage.

I am inserting few points with its quadkey into DB, and want to retrieve all points within a given radius using quadkeys.

Assume I have a point (46,46) whose quad key on a zoom level 23 is, 
12122022101301320022121 (using this [link](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/))

Now I want to search all the points in DB that are at a radius of 100km to a reference point, say (47,47)

My idea is, use the given distance (100km) to find a zoom level, form a quadkey for (47,47) with that level, and query the DB with this key to retrive all keys that has the given prefix.

Is this the right way of doing?
Or is there a better way to deal with this using quadkeys.

Comment: [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462580/retrieve-all-points-within-a-given-radius-using-quadkeys)